# name 'LoginRequiredMixin' is not defined in django

Tags: django, django-views

**My error is shown in below.**

> Name **'LoginRequiredMixin'** is not defined

```
class OrderSummaryView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            context = {
                'object': order
            }
            return render(self.request, 'order_summary.html', context)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("/")
```

How to import `LoginRequiredMixin` in django **views.py** file?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django has excellent documentation: [here are the docs for LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin). What you need is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
```